# Tripwire number of total violations reduced without updating database

Tags: tripwire

We are using Tripwire to watch over an Ubuntu server.
There is a daily report that is mailed to the admin.
On the report, there are violations that are expected, for example log file additions/removals/modifications.
At the end of the report, there is a Total Violation Count.
Is it possible for the Total Violations to reduce from one day to the next, even though the database hasn't been updated?
For example on Monday we had 90 Total Violations and on Tuesday, without updating the database, the violations dropped to 83.
On closer look, some files that showed as modified in the Monday report, were not showing in the Tuesday report, and there were not in the removed files either.
Should we be worried?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible?  Sure.

Based on similar products (AIDE, Integrit), there is some configurability regarding just what gets checked.  (I have used those products, which have described their configuration file as being similar to Tripwire, so likely they operate similarly).  If dates are not being checked, and changes that do get checked are reverted, then the count could drop.

For example, if permissions are checked, and one day a file is flipped to "read-only", that might be flagged as a change.  If this caused a problem for an end user, who complained, then the change may have been reverted.  The next report will not notice a change in the permissions.

I wouldn't expect this to happen much.  If it happened at all, it would probably be a minority of updates.  You are, in fact, reporting only 7 changes out of 90.  That seems to be within the realm of being commonly believable.

Now, regarding whether this actually is exactly what happened in your case, we may be unable to answer that without more details (like just what your configuration is, and what violations are being reported).  Sharing such details might, or might not, involve sharing information that should not be shared.  Some of this may depend on just how sensitive the information is.  However, if you want more precise details, that may be needed.